# Laravel 10 Route Suddenly Redirects to 404

Tags: php, laravel, http-status-code-404

I am at my wits end with this and have tried just about everything I could find shy of reverting all changes across the entire application to when it worked. The issue: /files/create suddenly started returning a 404 page instead of the proper contents. Below is a handful of relevant info I figured people might need. Let me know if you need more to help.

I've searched online and essentially tried the following:

- Clearing the route cache (as well as attempting to clear all cache)
- Putting the middleware group above the routes with parameters
- Testing other routes with the auth middleware as well as removing the routes from the auth middleware
- Testing the other /files routes (they work)
- Triple checking the existence and spelling of all relevant things (route, function, etc)
- Running php artisan optimize
- Running php artisan route:list to verify that the route is there
- Stopping the server and restarting it

**web.php**

```
Route::controller(FileController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/files', 'index');
    Route::get('/files/{id}', 'show');
    Route::get('/files/{id}/preview', 'preview');
    Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/files/create', 'create');
        Route::post('/files/create', 'store');
    });
});
```

**FileController.php**

```
public function create()
{
    return view('file.create');
}
```

**File Structure**
The desired view is stored in resources\views\file\create.blade.php. Worth noting that all other views under resources\views\file are accessed without problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I went through and figured out which specific change broke it. Turns out it was in web.php when going from this:

```
Route::controller(FileController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/files', 'index');
    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/files/create', 'create');
        Route::post('/files/create', 'store');
    });
});
```

To this:

```
Route::controller(FileController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/files', 'index');
    Route::get('/files/{id}', 'show');
    Route::get('/files/{id}/preview', 'preview');
    Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('/files/create', 'create');
        Route::post('/files/create', 'store');
    });
});
```

Before posting here, I did try to move the middleware group above the two added lines to see if it was an issue with the way Laravel processes routes from top to bottom. But **for some reason** deleting the changes in GitHub Desktop and re-adding the lines below the middleware group worked when the other way did not. Perhaps it was some order in which I cleared the cache and made the changes that was significant.